# Accessing JNDI from within Eclipse OSGI bundle, hosted in WebSphere App Server

Tags: jdbc, websphere, osgi, jndi

I have a problem accessing JNDI resources from within an OSGI bundle, hosted in

WebSphere Application Server (WAS) using a servlet bridge.

It is failing on creating the JNDI initial context. My code is:

Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
  "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);

This fails with:

javax.naming.NoInitialContextException:
 Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hashtable {java.naming.provider.url=corbaloc:rir:/NameServiceServerRoot, java.naming.factory.initial=com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.ibm.ws.naming:com.ibm.ws.runtime:com.ibm.iscportal.jndi} [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]

When I run the same code directly within a WAR module (not using OSGI), it is  successful. I assume therefore the problem is something about accessing JNDI from within OSGI.

I have seen some references to Class Loader problems when accessing JNDI from within OSGI ... not sure if this is my problem, since the above exception does not explicitly relate to class loading, but maybe it is. Anyhow, if this is the problem, I am not sure how to fix it!

Is it in fact possible to access JNDI and JDBC entries set up within WAS, from within my OSGI module?

My application is an Eclipse RAP (Rich Ajax Plugin), packaged into a WAR file using the Eclipse WAR Product Tooling described at:

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2010/08/17/equinoxrap-war-deployment-an-end-to-the-pain/

This works successfully so far, apart from the JNDI access.

Many thanks

David

Comment: That perhaps wouldn't solve your problem (hence it's in the form of a comment), but I would lose the `env.put(context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY....` line. The name of the initial context factory class is typically provided by the runtime environment already.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right that that line isn't needed, as that value is assumed by default anyway, but taking it out doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default the thread context classloader will be used to load the InitialContextFactory. This is probably (but no guarantee) your bundle's classloader. You have a couple of options:

1. Configure the org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation property. This is probably implicitly set to sun.*,com.sun.* so you want to change it to be sun.*,com.sun.*,com.ibm.websphere.naming.* I believe this can be set in the servlet bridge wars WEB-INF/launch.ini
2. You could also import comibm.websphere.naming which would require you to add to the launch.ini org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=com.ibm.websphere.naming

Either should work.
Good luck.